# Add Comment to Firebird Trigger using .Net FbBatchExecution

Tags: c#, .net, bash, comments, firebird

I am writing a DB upgrade script to be executed by my .Net programm using .Net 4.5 with FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and embedded Firebird.

In my script, I add a new trigger and want to have some comment in the trigger's code (in DDL, characters "--", "//" or "/*" would work fine...).

Now when I add some comment to the trigger, the FbBatchExecution seems to parse out the comment, leaving only an empty line in with the following code:

```
-- TRIGGER on NEWTABLE
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER NEWTRIGGER FOR NEWTABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS BEGIN
/* MY COMMENT.... */
IF (NEW.ID IS NULL OR NEW.ID = 0) THEN
NEW.ID = GEN_ID(NEWTABLE_SEQ, 1);
END^
```

Am I missing a special character to tell FbBatchExecution that this comment is NOT a batch file comment as the -- TRIGGER on NEWTABLE is, but that it should take this as part of the command?

Thanks for helping out!
Regards!
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known issue of `FbBatchExecution`: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-266.